# AURELIA - Computed fields

Tags: aurelia

I have an issue with computed fields in aurelia framework... 
Background:
eg: we have tree structure of classes (3 levels) for better expression we have HouseOfFlats, Floors and Flats. All classes are json array, every class has some properties as Price.

And what I need:
I need to create class 'Compute' which encapsulate the observe of the fields and  the class input will be function like

```
this.Price = ko.computed(function() {
   return self.Quantity() * $Flat.PricePerBoxStatic();
  });
```

Meaning, 1 house of flats, 3 floors, 5 flats on each floor. And when I change the price on flat I need to compute the price of all falts on the floor and the price of whole houseofflats. So the prices will be recalculated in whole tree immediately the price of flat has changed.

Thank you all for any idea how to solve this with some smart solution.

[picture for better understanding:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV0mO.png)

Comment: Unfortunately stack-overflow is not here to provide you with complete solutions. Questions should show that you have tried to solve this problem already. And at that point if you get stuck somewhere or need help, then stack-overflow is the right place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

so let's say `total` is what you are looking for.

in your view model:

```
  get total(): number {
    // put here your calculation logic and return your total
  }
```

in your view, simply use string interpolation:

```
<p>${total}</p>
```

whenever any of the variables that participate in the calculation of total change its values - the total will be recalculated and you will see the updated value in the view.

Comment: "whenever any of the variables that participate in the calculation of total change its values" -- 

That's wrong. By default, Aurelia uses dirty checking, meaning that unlike Knockout, it polls that property every (by default) 200 milliseconds, which means that a) there might be a slight delay between the dependent value changing and the updated value appearing on the screen and b) it has performance implications. But the `@computedFrom('dependentProperty1', dependentPropertyN')` decorator comes to the rescue.

Comment: @Balázs , what exactly would you pass as parameters to `@computedFrom` in the given context?

Comment: The names of each property whose values participate in the value calculation. So if a change of value of `propA` should cause it to be re-calculated, include it. If a change of value of `propB` should cause it too, include it as well. What it does it tells Aurelia to opt out of polling, because it can subscribe to those explicitly listed in the parameter list. To answer your question, the property names as strings. Note that this works directly and indirectly, i.e., your computeds can depend on other computeds etc.

Comment: if I got it right - what OP is trying to observe is an array of objects. `@computedFrom` does not seem to observe that very well https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/249